# User acts as Student and Teacher in my model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, associations

I have a Student, Teacher, and University model. A Teacher has_many Universities and a Student has_one University.

Currently there is no Teacher or Student model but a single model User. In this way what would be relation between User and University? And what would be the correct schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,you are lot confused with the associations.It is **`university has_many teachers`** not 
**`Teacher has_many Universities`** and also it is not **`Student has_one University`**,it is **`student belongs_to university`**.

And your point of giving only one model as **`User`** instead of having two models(**teacher and Student**) should be given like this

```
class University < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :teachers, :class_name => "User"
has_many :students, :class_name => "User"

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :university

end
```

And I would recommend to read these [**Guides**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) before going any further with associations.

Hope it helps!

**Update**

Well,in that point,you can do like this

```
class University < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :teacher, :class_name => "User",:foreign_key => 'user_id'
    has_many :students, :class_name => "User"

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :universities

 end
```

Comment: Pavan, thanks for your answer. :). Actually my scenario is something like that. Say, a teacher who works at different universities, I mean part-time. And he wants to manage his all students of all universities. In this way, I think I'm right that, Teacher has_many Universities and Student has_one University. Hope I made you understand.

Comment: @user3576284 Well,Ok i get your point.But one thing remains same as i said before.It is `student belongs_to university`

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for something called single table inheritance. Check out this article:
http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails

Comment: It would only be sti if the op wanted a Teacher and Student model stored in the users table. But they quite clearly said that wasn't what they wanted. Setting `class_name` on the association is the way to go.